# How to correctly update each() function in following example?

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach, each

Could you please help me to rewrite the piece of code to fit the 8.2 PHP:

```php
while ($this->init_activity = each($activity)) {
    list( $object, $method, $params ) = $activity[1];
```

The full piece:

```php
protected function callActivities() {
    do_action( 'vc_mapper_call_activities_before' );
    while ($this->init_activity = each($activity)) {
        list( $object, $method, $params ) = $activity[1]; 
            if ( 'mapper' === $object ) {
            switch ( $method ) {
                case 'map':
                    WPBMap::map( $params['tag'], $params['attributes'] );
                    break;
                case 'drop_param':
                    WPBMap::dropParam( $params['name'], $params['attribute_name'] );
                    break;
                case 'add_param':
                    WPBMap::addParam( $params['name'], $params['attribute'] );
                    break;
                case 'mutate_param':
                    WPBMap::mutateParam( $params['name'], $params['attribute'] );
                    break;
                case 'drop_all_shortcodes':
                    WPBMap::dropAllShortcodes();
                    break;
                case 'drop_shortcode':
                    WPBMap::dropShortcode( $params['name'] );
                    break;
                case 'modify':
                    WPBMap::modify( $params['name'], $params['setting_name'], $params['value'] );
                    break;
            }
```

I tried to rewrite line as that:

```php
foreach ($this->init_activity as $activity)
```

instead of

```php
while ($this->init_activity = each($activity))
```

But it didn't work out.

Comment: Well those two lined aren't remotely equivalent. The original _assigns_ something _to_ `$this->init_activity` _from_ `$activity` but your version tries to do the exact opposite.

Comment: Try `foreach ($activity as $act) { $this->init_activity = $act;` ...etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this, that should cover all use cases. It depends on how `$this->init_activity` is used later.

```
foreach ( $activity as $key => $value ) {
    $this->init_activity = [
        "1"     => $value,
        "value" => $value,
        "0"     => $key,
        "key"   => $key,
    ];

...
```